# Cassandra Access Restriction for data in Different Datacenters

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have a Cassandra cluster with 12 Nodes - 4 Data Centers

Keyspace1 - Replicated to DC1 and DC2
Keyspace2 - Replicated to DC3 and DC4

Issue : If I connect to a node in DC3 / DC4 and query keyspace1 am still able to access data though the data is not physically present in DC3 and DC4.

Question : Is there a way to restrict the data access for Keyspaces with out creating user permission on the keyspace level

Answer (score 0):

Without creating user permission on keyspace level you can't restrict user to access keyspace.

When you connect to node in DC3/DC4 that node will act as co-ordinator and default CONSISTENCY LEVEL is 1.
If you use CONSISTENCY LEVEL of LOCAL_QUORUM then you will not get data from kyespace1.

But as per my knowledge there is no way to stop user from changing consistency level.